# problem with designing html video - how to stop video buffering

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to design a video player like youtube player and when the mouse over the time line of the video,i want it to show a minimize image of the video on the time of the time line like youtube player

and to do this i have put two video tag in html file
one is the main video and the other is appear when mouse over the time line of the video with a currentTime of the time of time line where the mouse is above time line

but i noticed that this way is stress on the internet because the second video each time i set to it
the currentTime is buffering

is there a solution to stop buffering or any alternative way to show this minimize image

Comment: you may need to write an api that would extract still images from the video https://superuser.com/questions/575854/can-ffmpeg-extract-images-from-a-video-with-timestamps

Comment: I'm afraid there's no native out-of-the-box solution to show video timeline thumbnails. But you could create them while uploading a video, or use some JS if the guest server supports cross-origin requests...

Answer (score 0):

## Create video timeline thumbnails (*stills*)

The **best** you could do would be: on video upload, (i.e: using FFMPEG) to take still images/thumbnails of the video data. Than when you draw your seek-preview, simply take the desired thumbnail image index.

**Otherwise, you could:**

- Create a video element
- Create a canvas element
- Create an array to store the stills
- If a still does not exist in array:

  1. set the cloned video time
  2. grab the video data to canvas
  3. store the image data into the stills array
- If a still exists, just use that image

Here's a dirty code just to give you an idea:

```js
const totStills = 10;

const addSeekThumbnail = (EL) => {
  const VID = EL.querySelector("video");
  const DSK = document.createElement("div");
  const VSK = document.createElement("video");
  const CTX = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  const stills = new Array(totStills);

  VSK.setAttribute("preload", "metadata");
  VSK.setAttribute("crossorigin", "*");
  DSK.classList.add("videoSeek");
  VSK.src = VID.src;
  EL.append(DSK);

  VID.addEventListener("mousemove", seekShot);
  EL.addEventListener("mousemove", toggleSeek);
  EL.addEventListener("mouseleave", toggleSeek);

  function takeStill() {
    const i = VSK.dataset.fr * totStills;
    if (stills[i]) return;
    CTX.drawImage(VSK, 0, 0, VSK.videoWidth, VSK.videoHeight);
    stills[i] = CTX.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    loadStill()
  }

  function loadStill() {
    const i = VSK.dataset.fr * totStills;
    if (stills[i]) {
      DSK.style.backgroundImage = `url(${stills[i]})`;
    } else {
      DSK.style.backgroundImage = `none`;
      VSK.currentTime = Math.round(VSK.dataset.fr * VID.duration);
      VSK.addEventListener("seeked", takeStill, {
        once: true
      });
    }
  }

  function toggleSeek(ev) {
    if (ev.type === "mouseleave") {
      return DSK.classList.remove("show");
    }
    const bcr = EL.getBoundingClientRect();
    const my = ev.clientY - bcr.top;
    DSK.classList.toggle("show", bcr.height - my < 30);
  }

  function seekShot(ev) {
    const bcr = EL.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mx = ev.clientX - bcr.left;
    const x = mx / bcr.width;
    const fr = Math.round(x * totStills) / totStills;
    if (VSK.dataset.fr === fr) return;
    VSK.dataset.fr = fr;
    DSK.style.left = `${fr * 80}%`; // 80 because it's 20% wide
    loadStill();
  }
};

const ELS_frames = document.querySelectorAll(".videoFrame");
ELS_frames.forEach(addSeekThumbnail);
```

```css
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.videoFrame {
    display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.videoSeek {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  transition: opacity 0.3s, left 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.videoSeek.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoFrame">
  <video id="video" crossorigin="*" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ahmetaksungur/aksvideoplayer/main/videos/video-360.mp4" controls></video>
</div>
```